# Why doesn't the function cast a pointer correctly (from base class to derived class)

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr

What's the best way to have a function cast a pointer to a base type, to a pointer to derived type? Why doesn't the following work automatically?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <queue>

class Base{
public:
    Base() {};
};

class Derived : public Base{
public:
    Derived() : Base() {};
};

void foo(const std::shared_ptr<Derived>& dp){ // "wrong" signature
    std::cout << "it runs\n";
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::queue<std::shared_ptr<Base>> q;
    q.push( std::make_shared<Derived>() );
    foo(q.front()); // error

    return 0;
}
```

Replacing `foo` with the following works. However this might not enforce the argument to be a Derived class, which is the only thing it should be in the program I am writing.

```
void foo(const std::shared_ptr<Base>& dp){
    std::cout << "it runs\n";
}
```

I could probably also cast the pointer manually. Any other ideas?

**Edit:** 
a few people have suggested that I use virtual functions. I imagine that they mean I should put `foo` inside the classes as a virtual function like the following. However, if I am wrong, then please correct my understanding.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <queue>

class Base{
public:
    Base() {};
    virtual void foo () { std:: cout << "base\n"; };
};

class Derived : public Base{
public:
    Derived() : Base() {};
    void foo() {std::cout << "derived\n";};
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::queue<std::shared_ptr<Base>> q;
    q.push( std::make_shared<Derived>() );
    q.front()->foo();

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit 2:**
Thanks, everyone, for the help. At the moment I've accepted an answer, but in my real program I will probably lean toward using @alain's casting answer, actually. In this program, my queue is full of events that I pop off one at a time. In addition to this queue, I have multiple event-handlers--depending on what type of derived class it is, I will use a different event handler's function. So it doesn't make much sense to me to think about these event's possessing the event-handlers function. Actually this makes me think I need to reconsider having inheritance in the events altogether. I wouldn't have this issue at all if there was some queue that would allow objects of different type. Maybe that's bad for other reasons, though, I'm not sure.

Comment: The type of `q.front()` is `const std::shared_ptr<Base>&`. That's not a `const std::shared_ptr<Derived>&`. Sure, in this case you *know* that it's actually a `const std::shared_ptr<Derived>&`, but the compiler doesn't. In general, it can't / you can't. Either your queue should be `std::queue<std::shared_ptr<Derived>>`, or you might need to downcast (downcasting is usually a sign of bad design, though).

Comment: Remember: All `Derived` are `Base` but not all `Base` are `Derived`.

Comment: The "best" way is to use `virtual` functions.

Comment: @Justin are you suggesting that I make foo a member function and make it virtual? Or are you suggesting that the existence of a virtual function would help foo resolve this automatically? What if I can't put foo in a class?

Comment: Don’t use shared_ptr as function parameter when you don’t want to share ownership.

Comment: @Taylor You pretty much nailed it there. The only think you are missing is a virtual destructor for `Base`. The virtual destructor is required to allow the system to track down and destroy the correct objects when deleting a `Base`.  Leaving this out results in the dreaded Undefined Behaviour where many magical things could happen from the program appearing to work to the program raising an army of machines and exterminating all organic life on earth.

Comment: To answer the question in the edit: please don't ask two questions in one question ;) Without seeing all of the program I think it's impossible to say how the design could be improved. If you can make `foo` a virtual function and it solves a problem you can't solve in a simpler way: yes, do that.

Comment: Actually, these classes are not polymorphic (with the C++ definition of polymorphic class). There is no runtime polymorphism here.

Comment: @user4581301 "_The virtual destructor is required to allow the system to track down and destroy the correct objects_" actually it is not

Comment: @curiousguy **[class.virtual]** says: " A class that declares or inherits a virtual function is called a *polymorphic class.*" `virtual void foo () { std:: cout << "base\n"; };` is a virtual function. Checking with `std::is_polymorphic`: https://ideone.com/duUS7r

Comment: @user4581301 `class Base{
public:
    Base() {};
};
` no virtual function here

Comment: I see your confusion. My first comment was in response to the edit where Taylor started experimenting with `virtual` and asked if they had gotten anything wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::queue<std::shared_ptr<Base>> q;
```

is a queue of (shared) pointers to `Base`s, so

```
q.front()
```

will return a `std::shared_ptr<Base>`.

```
void foo(const std::shared_ptr<Derived>& dp)
```

Requires a `std::shared_ptr<Derived>`

While there is a relationship between `Base` and `Derived`, there is no relationship between `std::shared_ptr<Base>` and `std::shared_ptr<Derived>`. They are two different types of `shared_ptr`.

"Well then," you might think, "I will just `shared_ptr::get` the pointer out. Winning!" You can think that, but... no. `Derived` is a `Base`, but `Base` is not a `Derived`.

At this point you have two options: cast `Base` to a `Derived` since you know dang well that it is a `Derived`, but this is only really viable in toy code where you DO know it's a `Derived`. Real code gets messier. It's a bad idea.

So lets just skip to the good idea, shall we? Virtual Functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <queue>

class Base
{
public:
    // none of the constructors do anything, so I got rid of them.
    // code that's not there has no bugs.
    virtual ~Base() = default; // must provide virtual destructor so that
                               // correct destructors get called when a Base
                               // is destroyed
    virtual void foo() = 0; // pure virtual function. All descendants must
                            // provide this function
                            // Pure virtual has the side effect of  making 
                            // it impossible to instantiate a Base.
                            // This may or may not be what you want. If it 
                            // isn't, remove the =0 and implement the function.
/*
    virtual void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "I pity the foo who derives from Base.\n"
    }
*/
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    void foo() // implement Base::foo
    {
        std::cout << "it runs\n";
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::queue<std::shared_ptr<Base>> q;
    q.push(std::make_shared<Derived>());
    q.front()->foo();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well... We have not seen the program, so it's hard to give design recommendations. But mine was a quick answer of course :)

Answer (score 2):

Two changes are needed:

Enabling polymorphism by adding a `virtual` function to the `Base` class. It is a good idea to have a virtual destructor, so

```
virtual ~Base() {};
```

Then, a `std::shared_ptr<Base>` can't be converted to `std::shared_ptr<Derived>` automatically. You have to use a `dynamic_pointer_cast`:

```
foo(dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(q.front())); // error
```

Please also check if this is really needed, because designs not requiring casts from base to derived are usually better.

[Working code online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b71c18a06e65a68)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a **Virtual Function** in your Base class otherwise it will treat it as **Inheritance** not **Polymorphism** so it will not refer your child object with base class pointer.

Comment: so if I put a virtual in there not only will it resolve calls to that virtual function, but also it will resolve the objects type as well?

Comment: Because of that function it will be able to distinguish between the functionality that whether it should treat the child as one of its forms or not. So, yes, using virtual functions will solve your problem as Justin has already suggested it.

Comment: The functions which are common in your base class and child class, you should declare them as virtual in your base class and override them in child classes according to your functionality.